# force css grid container to fill full screen of device

Tags: html, css, css-grid

How do I force a css grid container take the full width and height of the device screen for a single page app? Modified example is from Mozilla: [Firefox documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Grid_Layout)

```css
.wrapper {
  display: grid;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: red;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
  grid-template-rows: repeat(3, 1fr);
  grid-gap: 10px;
}
.one {
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: blue;
  grid-column: 1 / 3;
  grid-row: 1;
}
.two {
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: yellow;
  grid-column: 2 / 4;
  grid-row: 1 / 3;
}
.three {
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: violet;
  grid-row: 2 / 5;
  grid-column: 1;
}
.four {
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: aqua;
  grid-column: 3;
  grid-row: 3;
}
.five {
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: green;
  grid-column: 2;
  grid-row: 4;
}
.six {
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: purple;
  grid-column: 3;
  grid-row: 4;
}
```

```html
<html>
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="one">One</div>
  <div class="two">Two</div>
  <div class="three">Three</div>
  <div class="four">Four</div>
  <div class="five">Five</div>
  <div class="six">Six</div>
</div>
</html>
```

I'm not sure what to do to get this code to work.

Answer (score 165, accepted):

If you take advantage of `width: 100vw;` and `height: 100vh;`, the object with these styles applied will stretch to the full width and height of the device.

Also note, there are times padding and margins can get added to your view, by browsers and the like. I added a `*` global no padding and margins so you can see the difference. Keep this in mind.

```css
*{
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
.wrapper {
  display: grid;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: red;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
  grid-template-rows: repeat(3, 1fr);
  grid-gap: 10px;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
}
.one {
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: blue;
  grid-column: 1 / 3;
  grid-row: 1;
}
.two {
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: yellow;
  grid-column: 2 / 4;
  grid-row: 1 / 3;
}
.three {
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: violet;
  grid-row: 2 / 5;
  grid-column: 1;
}
.four {
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: aqua;
  grid-column: 3;
  grid-row: 3;
}
.five {
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: green;
  grid-column: 2;
  grid-row: 4;
}
.six {
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: purple;
  grid-column: 3;
  grid-row: 4;
}
```

```html
<html>
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="one">One</div>
  <div class="two">Two</div>
  <div class="three">Three</div>
  <div class="four">Four</div>
  <div class="five">Five</div>
  <div class="six">Six</div>
</div>
</html>
```

Comment: sadly, this won't work in the generic case, (i.e. if you don't know whether or not your container is at the top level or not) because vw and vh are relative to the window size regardless of how nested your grid is.

Comment: ^ That is correct. This is for device width/height only, not nested containers stretching to full width/height of their parent. Nested containers will need appropriately sized parent containers with responsive CSS selectors such as % or ems for the children.

Comment: Keep in mind this may not work as intended with scrollbars. Per [the spec](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-values-3/#vh), "However, any scrollbars are assumed not to exist." With scrollbars that appear *on top* of content, this isn't an issue, but with scrollbars that add space for the scrollbar (typical), `100vh` or `100vw` may cause unwanted scrolling in the other scroll direction if a scrollbar is present. Compare https://jsfiddle.net/mtgk7vbe/4/ (50vw and no horizontal scrollbar) and https://jsfiddle.net/mtgk7vbe/5/ (100w and a horizontal scrollbar).

Comment: This works fine if you use vh on the body element only and percent from parent to child elements.

Comment: know that vh units are broken on mobile devices. I'd recommend to never use vh units unless your are in a special situation (no mobile, controlled environment)  https://nicolas-hoizey.com/articles/2015/02/18/viewport-height-is-taller-than-the-visible-part-of-the-document-in-some-mobile-browsers/

Comment: This adds unwanted scrollbars for me. In Chrome, at least, it seems to add any padding included in any nested elements at any level. Very, very frustrating. It's hard to believe I'm writing this in 2023 and we still can't get full height to work.

Comment: @DaveMunger, ensure you are resetting the browser-implemented styles around HTML elements. Mainly, reset the padding/margin for all elements to 0 using the * selector. box-sizing: border-box can also help where you need to account for the space padding does use, when used, to prevent overflow.

Comment: @NSTuttle I use a reset stylesheet that does all of that.

Comment: @NSTuttle Also have tried border-box sizing. Still get the unwanted vertical scrollbar.

Comment: Note this will also cause problems with virtual keyboards on mobile devices.

Answer (score 19):

Two important CSS properties to set for full height pages are these:

1. Allow the body to grow as high as the content in it requires.

   ```
    html { height: 100%; }
   ```
2. Force the body not to get any smaller than then window height.

   ```
    body { min-height: 100%; }
   ```

What you do with your grid is irrelevant as long as you use fractions or percentages you should be safe in all cases.

[Have a look at this common dashboard layout](https://jsfiddle.net/vg89whxh/).

Comment: i'd say that this answer is incorrectly mixing older CSS approaches with new, where you should be looking to use the accepted answer's more up-to-date approach. 
and although this answer may _work_, it also adds coupling between the html + body elements and the element being styled, so I'd recommend against this approach.

Comment: Set width 100% as well

Comment: The so called "older CSS approaches" are not all defunct. Using percentages isn't "outdated." Using vh and vw creates problems with scrollbars and virtual keyboards on mobile devices.

Answer (score 12):

Edit: Css now has [inset](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/inset) is a shorthand that corresponds to the top, right, bottom, and/or left. The new attribute is: `position: fixed; inset: 0;`

You can add the attribute `position: fixed; top: 0; left: 0; right: 0; bottom: 0;` to achieve a fixed position, and this solution will work on older browsers as well.

If you want to embed it, add `position: absolute;` to the wrapper and `position: relative;` to the div outside of the wrapper.

```css
.wrapper {
  position: fixed;
  inset: 0;

  display: grid;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: red;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
  grid-template-rows: repeat(3, 1fr);
  grid-gap: 10px;
}
.one {
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: blue;
  grid-column: 1 / 3;
  grid-row: 1;
}
.two {
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: yellow;
  grid-column: 2 / 4;
  grid-row: 1 / 3;
}
.three {
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: violet;
  grid-row: 2 / 5;
  grid-column: 1;
}
.four {
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: aqua;
  grid-column: 3;
  grid-row: 3;
}
.five {
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: green;
  grid-column: 2;
  grid-row: 4;
}
.six {
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: purple;
  grid-column: 3;
  grid-row: 4;
}
```

```html
<html>
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="one">One</div>
  <div class="two">Two</div>
  <div class="three">Three</div>
  <div class="four">Four</div>
  <div class="five">Five</div>
  <div class="six">Six</div>
</div>
</html>
```

Comment: i'd say that this answer is incorrectly mixing older CSS approaches with new, where you should be looking to use the accepted answer's more up-to-date approach, and in fact may be undoing some of the CSS Grid functionality, so I'd recommend against this approach.

Comment: @adarren This is the preferred method in the spec (from 2016): https://www.w3.org/TR/css-position-3/#abs-pos  using `width` and `height` ends up the same result, but represent different kind of logic: using the `top 0 right 0....`  method says: "I want this element to fill out the parent element", `width height` says "I want to this element has the same size than the parent element can contain"

Comment: This works way better for me (on Firefox) than the accepted answer. The accepted answer gives me scroll bars and changes size relative to the main document.

Comment: The so called "older CSS approaches" are not all defunct. Using position isn't "outdated." Using vh and vw per the accepted answer creates problems with scrollbars and virtual keyboards on mobile devices.

Comment: I really like this approach. In my tests it does exactly what I want: The grid is full-height unless the device is too short for the contents. Scrolling is possible then. Perfect.